# Reflecting texture register from a HLSL shader by name

Tags: shader, direct3d, hlsl

I know how to reflect constant buffers, but how do I reflect textures? Here's my shader:

```
cbuffer buffer : register(b0)
{
    column_major matrix viewProjectionMatrix;
    column_major matrix modelMatrix;
    float4 texScaleOffset;
    float4 tint;
}

struct VS_INPUT
{
    float4 Pos : POSITION;
    float2 Tex : TEXCOORD0;
};

struct PS_INPUT
{
    float4 Pos : SV_POSITION;
    float2 Tex : TEXCOORD0;
};

PS_INPUT VS( VS_INPUT input )
{
    PS_INPUT output = (PS_INPUT)0;
    output.Pos = mul( viewProjectionMatrix, mul( modelMatrix, input.Pos ) );
    output.Tex = input.Tex * texScaleOffset.xy + texScaleOffset.zw;

    return output;
}

Texture2D textureMap : register(t0);
SamplerState SampleType : register(s0);

float4 PS( PS_INPUT input ) : SV_Target
{
    return textureMap.Sample( SampleType, input.Tex );
}
```

So how do I query textureMap's register number from C++ if I know its name ("textureMap")? My use case is an engine that allows users to write their own shaders so I can't hardcode any values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a very similar way to how you reflect constant buffers:

```
ID3D11ShaderReflection* reflectionInterface;
D3DReflect(bytecode, bytecodeLength, IID_ID3D11ShaderReflection, (void**)&reflectionInterface);

D3D11_SHADER_INPUT_BIND_DESC bindDesc;
reflectionInterface->GetResourceBindingDescByName("textureMap", &bindDesc);
```

bindDesc.BindPoint is the index of the slot the texture is bound to.